# Не удаётся создать лист сопряжённых Bluetooth-устройств

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Не удаётся показать лист сопряжённых устройств, приложение всё время крашится вот с таким logcat

```
2020-04-15 17:22:18.866 18769-18769/com.example.reaction E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.reaction, PID: 18769
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.reaction/com.example.reaction.BluetoothConnect}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6396)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
     Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.reaction.BluetoothConnect.findArduino(BluetoothConnect.kt:82)
        at com.example.reaction.BluetoothConnect.onCreate(BluetoothConnect.kt:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
```

Вот MainActivity

```
private var bluetooth: BluetoothAdapter? = null
private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1
private lateinit var pairedDevises: Set<BluetoothDevice>
private var listView: ListView? = null
private var pairedDeviceArrayList: java.util.ArrayList<String>? = null
private var pairedDeviceAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
private var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
var clientSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null


class BluetoothConnect : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_connect)
         listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listViewDeices)
        val buttonStartFind = findViewById<Button>(R.id.ButtonStartSearch)
        addListenerOnButton()


        findArduino()

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }


        buttonStartFind.setOnClickListener {
            //если разрешения получены (функция ниже)
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

        }
    }

    private fun addListenerOnButton() {
        val intent_toReaction = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Intent_toReaction)



        intent_toReaction.setOnClickListener(
            View.OnClickListener {
                val intent3 = Intent(this@BluetoothConnect, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent3)
            }
        )
    }






    private fun findArduino() {
        //получить список доступных устройств
        val pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter!!.getBondedDevices()

        if (pairedDevice.size > 0) { //если есть хоть одно устройство
            pairedDeviceArrayList = ArrayList() //создать список
            for (device in pairedDevice) {
                //добавляем в список все найденные устройства
                //формат: "уникальный адрес/имя"
                pairedDeviceArrayList!!.add(device.address + "/" + device.name)
            }
        }
        //передаем список адаптеру, пригождается созданный ранее item_device.xml
        pairedDeviceAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
            applicationContext,
            R.layout.item_device,
            R.id.item_device_textView,
            pairedDeviceArrayList
        )
        listView!!.setAdapter(pairedDeviceAdapter)
        //на каждый элемент списка вешаем слушатель
        listView!!.setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
            //через костыль получаем адрес
            val itemMAC =
                listView!!.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().split("/".toRegex(), 2).toTypedArray()[0]
            //получаем класс с информацией об устройстве
            val connectDevice = bluetoothAdapter!!.getRemoteDevice(itemMAC)
            try {
                //генерируем socket - поток, через который будут посылаться данные
                val m = connectDevice.javaClass.getMethod(
                    "createRfcommSocket", *arrayOf<Class<*>>(Int::class.javaPrimitiveType!!)
                )

                clientSocket = m.invoke(connectDevice, 1) as BluetoothSocket
                clientSocket!!.connect()
                if (clientSocket!!.isConnected()) {
                    //если соединение установлено, завершаем поиск
                    bluetoothAdapter!!.cancelDiscovery()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.stackTrace
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

У вас переменные которые вы в классе используете объявлены за его пределами. Вот эти переменные:

```
private var bluetooth: BluetoothAdapter? = null
private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1
private lateinit var pairedDevises: Set<BluetoothDevice>
private var listView: ListView? = null
private var pairedDeviceArrayList: java.util.ArrayList<String>? = null
private var pairedDeviceAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
private var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
var clientSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null
```

переместите в тело класса:

```
class BluetoothConnect : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var bluetooth: BluetoothAdapter? = null
    private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1
    private lateinit var pairedDevises: Set<BluetoothDevice>
    private var listView: ListView? = null
    private var pairedDeviceArrayList: java.util.ArrayList<String>? = null
    private var pairedDeviceAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
    private var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
    var clientSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     ....
    }
}
```